# In the Court Jester, what are the Spanish words Danny Kaye says after "Rodriguez" in his performance of Maladjusted Jester?

Tags: analysis, dialogue

In [*The Court Jester* (1955)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049096/), Hawkins (played by Danny Kaye) performs his own rendition of the Maladjusted Jester. One of his twists is the burst of Spanish words about two thirds into the song, after he says "and stand... and stand... Rodriguez--". Out of curiosity, and also because I want to memorize Kaye's version of the song, what are the Spanish words he says there and what is their meaning?

Link to the part:

Using 0.25 speed on Youtube, this is what I've gotten so far:

"Rodriguez, pronto de viende estado lugar de su [nonsense:] son de vivar es y em g his majesty"

It makes sense until "su son...", as Google Translate says that it means "Rodriguez, soon to be the place of his...", which could be connected to the plot (the baby taking the place of the false king). But the rest is nonsensical to me. Kaye might be combining some English words beyond "his majesty" at the end. Could someone, maybe a native Spanish speaker, decipher the rest of the words and their meaning?

My three years of high school Spanish are not helping much. Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure why this was flagged as trivia? Without knowing the translation of the words, we can't be certain that the choice to include them doesn't either have an impact on the scene or connecting to other parts/ideas presented in the film. I'm not saying it can't be some fun throw away thing, but IMO without answering it, we don't know that yet. Granted maybe the OP should point that out, making it more than a curiosity...